# Set Global Variable In Multer Variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am using multer to upload an image and I am generating a link to save into a database however to do this I am first saving the file to the server. The "link" is the name of the file along with it's extension but I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to set the global variable for "link" to save later on in the database OR perhaps run a function?

```
var link;
var storeImageData = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        var fileType = file.originalname;
        link = shortid.generate() + "." + fileType;
        callback(null, link);
    }
});

console.log(link);
```

As you can see I am trying to set "link" but this obviously won't work. Is there some way to make this work? Or something I should be looking into?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the link `req` and access that when saving to the db. heres an example:

In your filename function:

```
filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        var fileType = file.originalname;
        link = shortid.generate() + "." + fileType;
        req.link = link;    //add this line
        callback(null, link);
    }
```

Then in your "save to db" middlware you can get the link at req.link.

Comment: Thank you for your input, Sello. I wasn't able to use this in the end as req.link was not accessible in my middleware. However I realised in the end the reason why my code wasn't working was because the placement of my global variable was not in the right block. It is now working perfectly with this rectified. As I am using socket.io, my global variable had to be placed outside fo the main socket connection.